# Time dialtion when objects run in the same direction

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time-dilation

Just trying to understand the basics.
I saw some videos claiming  that when you run towards light the speed of light may appear  to be faster than C therefore time corrects it by being slow.

Now the naturally following question is suppose I dont run towards light. But rather we both are running in the same direction  (not towards each other)  suppose light is running on train and I am on the bus we both go at same direction. Light is running with C velocity and I do at 0.5C velocity.  If I measure  speed of the light I would assume it is 0.5C correct?
So in this scenario my assumption is that light runs at half of it's real speed. So in order to correct it wouldn't time have to go faster actually?

Summary: 2 scenarios:

1. you are running towards light. So it looks like 2C speed. We correct it by time dialtion.
2. you are running in lights direction light doesnt go towards you (but behind or a head of you). Then light would  appear as 0.5C speed.

Shouldn't  the correction in second scenario have to be time running faster?

Basically how does relativity deals with these 2 scenarios 1 is when light seems to be 2C the other is when light appears as 0.5C. I would assume time dialtion might fix only one way but would fail in the other. How is it possible to claim that in general moving faster would slow you down?

Anyone can correct my intuition? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you add a link to the video?

Comment: @garyp Well nearly every video I watched on the topic provides the same illustration.  Just picked this at random https://youtu.be/yuD34tEpRFw  at 2:55 they talk about an observer who runs towards light. In order for him not to get it with a higher than C speed time corrects it by going slow. But a simple counterexample would be when observer doesnt run towards but rather runs away from light when both at same direction. For him light would be more slow than C . Wouldn't time here need be faster to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light will always appear to be c to you, regardless of how quickly you move relative to other things or whether you are moving towards or away from the direction of motion of the light. Time dilation doesn't explain it, as you have seen for yourself. The point you need to take into account is the relativity of simultaneity. I strongly recommend you study that until you understand it, because time dilation, length contraction and all the paradoxes of SR are explainable as a consequence of the relativity of simultaneity.

In short, if you are moving through some reference frame, a level plane of constant time in your frame corresponds to a tilted slice through time in the other frame, the slice sloping upwards in your direction of travel. That means that at a given instant in your frame, say when it is exactly 10:33, it is 10:33 everywhere ahead and behind you in your frame. In the frame in which you are moving, the time might be 10:33 exactly where you are, but everywhere else ahead of you it is progressively later than 10:33 and everywhere else behind you it is progressively earlier than 10:33.

The effect is entirely reciprocal, so a level plane of constant time in the other frame is a tilted slice through time in your frame.

The concept is not one that is easy to grasp, but, as I mentioned earlier, it is the cause of all the other commonly mentioned effects of SR, and provides the resolution to all the so-called paradoxes of SR.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand the answer.  Anyways at least you agree that time dialtion in itself cant explain it when the assumed  velocity looks like 0.5C. But I didnt understand your answer. You wrote "In the frame in which you are moving, the time might be 10:33 exactly..." aren't you contradicting yourself one paragraph above?

Comment: You don't understand my answer because you don't understand the relativity of simultaneity!!!! That is my point- you need to study it until you do understand it!